# How to convert this to Json in Java/Android?

Tags: java, android, json, getjson, json-deserialization

I would like to convert this, which I don't know what it's called, to Json. Can you help me?

`[{key1=value1,key2=value2,key3=value3}]`

The result has to be this:
`{
"key1":"value1",
"key2":"value2",
"key3":"value3"
}`

Comment: Where did the string come from? It looks like you called `toString()` on a `List<Map<...,...>>`. If so, any JSON library should be able to convert the list itself to JSON.

Comment: @kaya3 This has nothing to do with "toString"

Comment: Well, I'm asking what outputted the string in this format.

Comment: @kaya3 Oh sorry, This happens when I put a json string in the map variable and pull the value of a key containing object. I can't explain very well...

Comment: are you sure use `=` ?

Comment: @bekt Jeez, let me correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is the contents of a `Map` object, you can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to convert between Java objects (including custom objects) into JSON, and JSON back into an object. That would look like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(YOUR_MAP);
```

Going back to a map:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<KEY_TYPE, VALUE_TYPE>>(){}.getType();
Map YOUR_MAP = gson.fromJson(JSON, type);
```

And if this is not a `Map` and just a strange string that wants to be a `Map` but couldn't quite make it you can just format the string by:

1. Removing both sets of brackets at the ends using the `substring(int start, int end)` method
2. Separate the entries by the commas and equals by using `split(",|=")`
3. Reassembling the `String` with the quotes as `JSON`

   - `String JSON = "{ \"" + arrayFromOriginalString[1] + "\":\"", arrayFromOriginalString[2]...` assuming the source string always has the same amount of entries
   - If the source is always different you can use a `for` loop and increment by 2

     ```
     String json = "{";

     for(int i = 0; i < YOUR_ARRAY.length; i += 2;) {
         json += "\"" + YOUR_ARRAY[i] + "\":\"" + YOUR_ARRAY[i + 1] + "\"";

         //Some kind of if condition to decide if a comma is required (Last entry)
     }

     json += "}";
     ```

[Here is a fully functioning example of this code](https://github.com/Weirdest/Examples/blob/master/user9761266/MapQuestion.java)

Comment: I will try this

Comment: Take a look at the updated question.

Comment: @user9761266 I have updated the answer

Comment: @user9761266 If this answer suits your needs please accept it as the answer

Comment: Hey, can you call me on Discord?